# How to bypass NoneType error in HTML with breaks

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributes, screen-scraping

I am scraping a website for reviews, and i am using the None exception as well, but NoneType error is still being shown, as mentioned below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/QB/Desktop/other.py", line 14, in <module>
    card = card_container.text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

The code I used is mentioned below:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.productreview.com.au/listings/american-express-platinum#reviews'
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
containers = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mb-3_X8n card_364 card-full_37I card-full-md_3Xd"})

for container in containers:

    card_container = container.find("h4", {"class": "my-0_27D align-items-baseline_kxl flex-row_3gP d-inline-flex_1j8 text-muted_2v5"})
    card = card_container.text.strip()
    title_container = container.find("h3", {"class": "mb-2_3ol"})
    title = title_container.text.strip()
    description_container = container.find("p", {"class": "mb-0_2CX"})
    description = description_container.text.strip()

    if None in (card, title, description):
        continue

    #if None in (card_container, title_container, description_container):
        #continue

    print(card)
    print(title)
    print(description)
```

Comment: Please include the traceback. You are not protecting against `find` returning `None` so presumably the error happens when you attempt to do `None.text.strip()`

Comment: Also, please take care not to trample previous edits when updating your question.